# Continuous rotation with transform and transitions

Tags: css, less, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to put a DOM element in 12 different rotation positions. I know this is perfectly possible using simple javascript animation of the css properties, but i would really like to get this working using css transforms/transitions.

So, consider this less snippet:

```
.setRotation (@degrees) {
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(@degrees);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(@degrees);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(@degrees);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(@degrees);
    transform: rotateZ(@degrees);
}

img {

    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -o-transition-property: transform;
    -ms-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    &.pos0 {
        .setRotation (15deg)
    }

    &.pos1 {
        .setRotation (45deg)
    }

    &.pos2 {
        .setRotation (75deg)
    }

    &.pos3 {
        .setRotation (105deg)
    }

    &.pos4 {
        .setRotation (135deg)
    }

    &.pos5 {
        .setRotation (165deg)
    }

    &.pos6 {
        .setRotation (195deg)
    }

    &.pos7 {
        .setRotation (225deg)
    }

    &.pos8 {
        .setRotation (255deg)
    }

    &.pos9 {
        .setRotation (285deg)
    }

    &.pos10 {
        .setRotation (315deg)
    }

    &.pos11 {
        .setRotation (345deg)
    }
}
```

I can now easily rotate to these 12 different positions by simply applying the corresponding class, and the transition works fine.

BUT: when transitioning from .pos11 to .pos0, it does not rotate 30 degrees clockwise but 330 counter clockwise. That makes sense of course, it simply transitions from 345 to 15. I could fix this by transitioning from 345 degrees to 375 degrees, but that makes it hard to use predefined css classes.

Any ideas to get this working? I can always revert to javascript animation as a workaround, but i really prefer css transitions.

Comment: and you are putting .posxx classes on some event in javascript?

Comment: Yes. I simply have a button with a click event where i apply these classes to the elements i want to rotate.

Comment: Just saw this question pop up in my statistics, here is the working result i ended up with eventually: http://chordoracle.com/dick_boaks_chord_wheel/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4zn/13/)**

**Technique:**

Simple Version: Using a visual similar but less degree value without transition to move degree to a more lesser value to start animation from lower values.

Detailed Version: I have added one more position before `pos0` which is `pos-1`, it has the same visual degree angle as `pos11` but the degree value is less then `pos0`, Also on `pos-1` transition is set to none so when you switch from pos11 to pos-1 you wont notice any difference visual but the rotation value would have been set to less then `pos0`, now you can easily jump from `pos-1` to `pos0` with smooth clockwise animation -- hope i am explaining it clearly.

**How to apply in your workflow:** What ever method you are using to switch classes, add a condition while switching from pos11 to pos0 just for a mini sec switch from pos11 to pos-1 then to pos0.

**NOTE:** I am more familiar with sass so i have used sass in demo below is the less version of the scss i have added:

**less:**

```
&.pos-1 {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition:    none;
    -o-transition:      none;
    -ms-transition:     none;
    transition:         none;
    .setRotation (-15deg)
}
```

Comment: This sound like a good solution Imran, will give it a try this evening and let you know.

Comment: how to use the demo? note about the OP's comment here ***I simply have a button with a click event where i apply these classes*** your demo should have a button, and I guess that, clicking that button will add each class to the element in the order the OP wants. That may have to re-cycle with ***clockwise animation***. So the problem is not just the transition between `pos11` and `pos0`.

Comment: @King King do you mean something like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4zn/10/) & what does OP's means?

Comment: @ImranBughio your demo does not work, how could I know if that is what I meant?

Comment: here is the demo which I think may be what the OP wants  http://jsfiddle.net/uR7ab/ but of course transition from `pos11` to `pos0` won't work expectedly.

Comment: @ImranBughio ah, that DEMO is OK now. Looks like it works. So +1 from me. Next time please post some easy-to-use demo, you'll receive more upvotes.

Comment: @ImranBughio you don't understand my idea, I just wanted to show the demo to explain how the button should work. and I already said ***but of course transition from pos11 to pos0 won't work expectedly***.

Comment: @KingKing i just realized your demo is webkit specific & you are right about the proper demo, i will keep that in mind -- Thanks King King

Comment: Imrans idea was very well explained, a fully working demo wasnt really necessary ;)